# Actualizar textbox en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

Soy nueva en c# wpf (perdón si tengo demasiados errores)
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación desktop en c# wpf donde, tengo un servidor socket que escucha un dato, esto lo envía a un modelo y en el modelo quiero actualizar la vista.
El problema es que no logro que el dato que envió, se actualice en el textbox asignado.
En el code behind veo que el textbox tiene ese dato, pero igual no aparece en la vista.

**El ViewModel**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    sealed class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private User user;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return user.FirstName; }
            set
            {
                if (user.FirstName != value)
                {
                    user.FirstName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                   
                }
            }
        }

        public MyViewModel()
        {

            user = new User
            {
                FirstName = "Karina"
            };

        }


        public void CambiarNombre(string dato)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Llego: " + dato);
             user = new User
            {
                FirstName = dato
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo que textbox estas tratando de cambiar... y la propiedad que pasas porque es text? no deberia ser FirstName, que es la propiedad que realmente cambias y la que deberia estar asociada a tu textbox?

Comment: Estoy tratando de cambiar este textbox  ```<TextBox x:Name = "nameText" Grid.Column = "1" Margin = "2" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>``` Ya cambie la propiedad de Text a FirstName, pero igual no funciona.

Comment: Y que errores ves en el debug? porque si esta mal el binding, vas a tener errores...

Comment: No muestra errores en el debug, al ejecutar, el textbox toma el valor asignado por primera vez "Karina". Pero no cambia luego de que recibe el dato que estoy enviado por socket

Comment: Estas trabajando en lo mismo que https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423841/como-puedo-mostrar-texto-en-una-ventana-wpf-desde-un-metodo-en-codigo-c??? sus preguntas son sospechosamente similares y con el mismo problema....

Comment: Si actualizaste el codigo, por favor actualizalo en la pregunta. como le asignas el valor Karina la primera vez?

Comment: Hola! La verdad es que me he dado cuenta, que el enfoque estaba mal. Ahora estoy probando con otros metodos que aun no me funcionan, pero voy a formular otra pregunta. Gracias de todos modos!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer esto:

En el Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Etiqueta}" Margin="0,0,426.6,339" />
        <Button Content="Cambiar" Command="{Binding Comando}" Margin="405,0,-0.4,339" />
    </Grid>
```

El modelo

```
MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _etiqueta;

    public string Etiqueta
    {
        get { return _etiqueta; }
        set
        {
            _etiqueta = value;
            PropertyUpdated();
        }
    }

    // Descargar paquete MvvmLight
    public RelayCommand Comando { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel() {
        Comando = new RelayCommand(ComandoExecute);
    }

    public void ComandoExecute() {
        Random r = new Random();
        Etiqueta = $"Hola número : {r.Next(999)}";
    }
}
```

NotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void PropertyUpdated([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Ligar el modelo a la vista

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Y listo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]