# Como puedo mostrar texto en una ventana WPF desde un metodo en codigo c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy por tirar la computadora, quiero mostrar un string en una ventana, este string lo mando desde un Socket Server mediante un metodo (Mensajito) a otro metodo (NroTicket) del Main Window.

Del Socket Server:

```
public void Mensajitooo(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ANTES DE...");
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.NroTicket(data);
            Console.WriteLine("Que lo que pasa");
        }
```

Al MainWindow:

```
        public void NroTicket(string dato)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Llego: " + dato);
            nameText.Text = dato;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }));
        }
```

El string llega a NroTicket pero en la ventana no se actualiza al valor del string. He tratado de mil formas pero ninguna con resultados, al parecer nameText.Text solo funciona en el constructor pero no me sirve porque necesito pasarle el string de alguna forma.

Tambien dejo el codigo importante en el XAML:

```
      <TextBox x:Name = "nameText" Grid.Column = "1" Margin = "2" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: El metodo `Mensajitooo` esta en la clase `MainWindow`?

Comment: Porque eliminaste una pregunta exactamente igual donde te habia dado un seguimiento y una respuesta?

Comment: `Mensajitooo` esta en la clase SocketServer.cs, elimine la pregunta porque estaba tratando de pasarle a unos companheros y no podia porque la pusiste como duplicada.

Comment: la puse como duplicada, porque la duplicada contestaba exactamente tu problema. tengo que poner esta tambien como duplicada porque es el mismo problema.. No se que quiere decir que tratabas de pasarla a unos compañeros... La duplicada, no contesta tu problema? que es que estas levantando otra ventana distinta cada vez que llega un mensaje?

Comment: No contesta mi pregunta para nada, porque yo tengo que pasarle al MainWindow el dato entonces creo un objeto de MainWindow y le paso el string al metodo NroTicket del MainWindow. El dato LLEGA a dicho metodo del MainWindow como string pero no se actualiza en el TextBox que quiero mostrar..

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir lo que dije antes... la duplicada contesta tu pregunta, porque esto: MainWindow mw = new MainWindow(); Crea una nueva ventana.. no es la misma ventana que ves... tenes que pasarle a esa clase la ventana sobre la que queres trabajar...

Comment: Como bien dice @gbianchi, estas creando una nueva instancia de MainWindow, por lo que aunque crees que estás llamando a NroTicket de tu ventana principal, en realidad no lo estás haciendo